# Dative or nominative in "Die Kindern hängen von Ihrem Vater ab."

Tags: dative, nominative

How to understand the following sentence:

> Die Kindern hängen von Ihrem Vater ab.

It sounds like the children depend on their father, right? Sorry, I am a Brazilian student. As I can see it, *Die Kindern* must be the subject, but wouldn't it then be *Die Kinder* [without *-n*]? If it were dative declination, it should be *Den Kindern*, right?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the dative would be "Den Kindern", however, that is the subject of the sentence so it should be the nominative, "Die Kinder".

Also, "Ihrem" probably should not be capitalized since that would be translated as "your", making it read "on your father". If the intent is "on their father" then it should be "von ihrem Vater".